# Paging output from python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement something similar to `git log`, which will only page the output if the log is of a certain length.  If you're not familiar with git, I'm essentially trying to achieve this:

```
python some_script.py | less
```

With some help from the paging implementation in python2.6/pydoc.py, I was able to come up with this:

```
import os
text = '...some text...'
pipe = os.popen('less', 'w')
pipe.write(text)
pipe.close()
```

which works great, but os.popen() is deprecated. I've considered writing to a temp file and calling less with its path, but that doesn't seem ideal. Is this possible with subprocess? Any other ideas?

EDIT:

So I've gotten subprocess working. I was able to give it the text variable with `Popen.communicate(text)`, but since I really want to redirect print statements, I've settled on this:

```
  import os, sys, subprocess, tempfile

  page = True
  if page:
      path = tempfile.mkstemp()[1]
      tmp_file = open(path, 'a')
      sys.stdout = tmp_file
  print '...some text...'
  if page:
      tmp_file.flush()
      tmp_file.close()
      p = subprocess.Popen(['less', path], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
      p.communicate()
      sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Of course, I'd end up wrapping it into functions.  Does anyone see a problem with that?

Comment: A few remarks: (1) the temporary file name is unique: the opening mode should be 'w', not 'a' (impossible to append to file).  (2) There is no need to `close()` the file before reading it.  (3) There is no need to communicate with the pager process (a simple `subprocess.call()` suffices).  (4) It is more explicit to not tamper with a global like `sys.stdout`; unless you really need to do this (like if you want to redirect the output of all the submodules that you use), it is a good idea to explicitly call a special printing function.

Comment: This is similar topic with nice and pithy Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584717/how-to-write-python-script-with-man-page-like-out-put/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use subprocess.Popen instead.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

There is even a note about this in the os.popen docs.

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried. Couldn't get it working at first, but it is now. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I gave it to you. I was hoping for some more general implementation advice if you have any--see my edit.

Comment: Wish I could help you more but I'm on Windows right now and none of these work for me, even when supplied the full path of my MSYS supplied less.

Comment: @eryksun Less works fine for me, the MYS bin dir is also in my path; just neither of the above python scripts works for me. Do they work for you?

Answer (score 54):

How about this:

```
import pydoc
text = '... some text ... '
pydoc.pager(text)
```

This (on my opensuse linux box) sends the text to a pager ('less' in my case), and works the same as calling "help(... python command...)" within the Python interpreter.

Comment: While I doubt that this function will not be available in the future, [it is not documented](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pydoc.html), unfortunately, so in principles it is not fully guaranteed that it will remain available. Given how convenient it is, though, I guess that this is a risk that should often be worth it. Furthermore, the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/pydoc.py#l1406) looks like it can easily be copied anyway.

Comment: It breaks my output when tried to print a formatted json data.

Comment: 6 years later, this approach still works in Python 3.7.2 ;-)

Comment: 10 years later, still works in Python 3.11.3

Answer (score 4):

It is a good idea to be explicit in your code, so that it shows that you use a special print function `printc()` instead of the standard one.  Using `subprocess.call()` is also sufficient (you don't need the pipe machinery).  Furthermore, you can save a variable by not storing the name of the temporary file:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import subprocess, tempfile

page = True  # For tests

# Definition of a printc() function that prints to the correct output
if page:
    tmp_file = open(tempfile.mkstemp()[1], 'w')  # No need to store the name in a specific variable
    def printc(*largs, **kwargs):
        if 'file' not in kwargs:  # The code can still use the usual file argument of print()
            kwargs['file'] = tmp_file  # Forces the output to go to the temp file
        print(*largs, **kwargs)
else:
    printc = print  # Regular print

# Main program:

printc('...some text...', 'some more text', sep='/')  # Python3 syntax

# Paging of the current contents of the temp file:
if page:
    tmp_file.flush()  # No need to close the file: you can keep printing to it
    subprocess.call(['less', tmp_file.name])  # Simpler than a full Popen()
```

This way, you get the flexibility of Python 3's `print` function, with a code that explicitly shows that you're doing some fancy printing stuff.  This scales better with larger programs than modifying the "global" `sys.stdout` variable in some locations of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've added your optimizations. I do need to redirect submodule output, like you mentioned in the comment, so it seems like I'm stuck with the sys.stdout approach. I've put this all into a class, so it can be called with `pager = Pager()` and `pager.begin()`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't like executing external commands, so I wrote [pager](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pager) in pure Python. It still has a problem - piped input works only for Windows.

Comment: @MichaelR, please open a bugreport here - https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-pager/issues so that it won't lost.

Answer (score 2):

With one caveat, this works for me as a way to redirect process output to a pager on Linux (I don't have Windows handy to test there) when, for whatever reason, it's not feasible to write it all to a file or `StringIO` and then feed it to the pager all at once:

```py
import os, sys

less = None
if os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno()):
    less = subprocess.Popen(
        ['less', '-R', '--quit-if-one-screen'],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    os.dup2(less.stdin.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
```

Now for the caveat:

`less` behaves as if `-E` has been passed and terminates when I reach the bottom of the output. I assume that's because, as the child of the script, it's dying when the script does, but adding the following to the end of the script just causes `less` to hang when it would otherwise have exited and I haven't had time to figure out why:

```
if less:
    less.stdin.close()  # no different with or without
    less.communicate()  # no different with less.wait()
```

(It wasn't an issue when I first came up with this hack because I originated it for making a PyGTK 2.x program pipe its output to grep to work around PyGTK not exposing the function from the GTK+ C API needed to silence some spurious log messages.)

Comment: Doing both os.close(less.stdin.fileno()) and os.close(sys.stdout.fileno()) seems to work

Answer (score 0):

In py2.7 I was able to do just

```
    sys.stdout = os.popen(pager, 'w')
```

but this stopped working in py3.  Some of the above solutions didn't seem to work for me, but I wrote this decorator that does:

```
  def _get_pager_name():                                
      for p in (os.environ.get('PAGER', ''), '/usr/bin/less', '/bin/more', 'cat'):                                
          if Path(p).is_file():                                
              return p                                
      return None                                
                                  
                                  
  def paged(f):                                
      @wraps(f)                                
      def wrapper(*a, **kw):                                
          try:                                
              with subprocess.Popen([_get_pager_name()], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True) as p:                                
                  sys.stdout = p.stdin                                
                  return f(*a, **kw)                                
          finally:                                
              sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__                                
                                  
      pager = _get_pager_name()                                
      return wrapper if sys.stdout.isatty() and pager else f
```