# Git like Interactive list view in python

Tags: python, interactive

I want to display a long list interactively in a python command line program. 
Basically, think `git log`, with the scrolling and the q to quit.

How would I do this in python?

Comment: You should specify where the data for something like this is coming from, how much of it you want to show on screen, if you'd allow for going back and forth (since `git log` does allow you to do that), or if it'd be worth doing any of that at all and relying on `less` instead (for the *nix terminal - including Mac).

Answer (score 1):

The interactive view that git has is called a pager. Git just uses the pager `less`, or a different one if you configure it.

Basically you need to run `less` in a subprocess and pipe your output to it.

There are more details on how to do that in this question: [Paging output from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728661/paging-output-from-python)

There is also a python helper library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pager (I've not used it)

Answer (score -1):

Create a while loop and ask inputs from the prompt.

Eg:

```
import msvcrt

my_lis = range(1,78)
limit = 25
my_inp = None

while my_lis:
    if my_inp != 'q':
        print my_lis[:limit]
        my_lis = my_lis[limit:]
    else:
        break   
    print "Press any key to continue or (q) to Quit :"
    my_inp = msvcrt.getch()
# Exit
```