# How to write python script with man-page like out-put

Tags: python, bash, shell, manpage

I wonder how to write a script with stdout like command-line like 'more', 'less', 'man' which it is seems they show their result in another layer of bash.
how can I write a program with such output in python?

Comment: Do you want to rewrite `less` or do you want to show the output of your programm in `less` ? `python3 your_program.py | less` is the typical way to do it.

Comment: `less` is a class of program called a "pager" or ["terminal pager"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager)

Comment: Best help! I did look for program class name "pager" @HåkenLid

Answer (score 0):

You can use pydoc.pager for that. It's in the standard library.

```
from pydoc import pager
pager('hello world\n' * 100)
```