# How to print to terminal like git log?

Tags: python, linux, stdout

I'm writing a simple CLI application using python.
I have a list of records that I want to print in the terminal and I would like to output them just like git log does. So as a partial list you can load more using the down arrow, from which you quit by typing "q" (basically like the output of *less*, but without opening and closing a file).

How does git log do that?

Comment: Nothing to do with git. I erased the off-topic tags.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728661/paging-output-from-python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device you are looking for is called *pager*, there exists `pipepager` function inside [`pydoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html), which is not documented in linked pydoc docs, but using interactive python console you might learn that

```
>>> help(pydoc.pipepager)
Help on function pipepager in module pydoc:

pipepager(text, cmd)
    Page through text by feeding it to another program.
```

therefore it seems that you should use this as follows

```
import pydoc
pydoc.pipepager("your text here", "less")
```

with limitation that it does depends on availability of `less` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe directly to a pager like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58893594/6333444) should work.

Alternatively, you can use a temporary file:

```py
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess

# File contents for testing, replace with whatever
file = '\n'.join(f"{i} abc 123"*15 for i in range(400))

# Save the file to the disk
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+', delete=False) as f:
        f.write(file)

# Run `less` on the saved file
subprocess.check_call(["less", f.name])

# Delete the temporary file now that we are done with it.
os.unlink(f.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How does git log do that?

`git log` invokes `less` when the output will not fit on the terminal. You can check that by running `git log` (if the repo doesn't have a lot of commits you can just resize the terminal before running the command) and then checking the running processes like so `ps aux | grep less`